# windows - gcloud ssh throwing potential security breach error

Tags: windows, ssh, google-compute-engine, putty, gcloud

Please note - this is platform specific. I tried this on

```
>>> print sys.platform
'darwin'
```

and the code has no issue. Yet, on

```
>>> print sys.platform
'win32'
```

I get the issue.

Additionally, I am able to winscp into the instance without issue.

---

I am running the following gcloud ssh command:

```
gcloud compute ssh  my-instance --zone=us-east1-b --command="sudo -S -i -u root -p '' echo 'git -C /root/git/v_a stash;git -C /root/git/v_a pull https://user:pass@bitbucket.org/user/v_a.git;git -C /root/git/gcloud stash;git -C /root/git/gcloud pull https://user:pass@bitbucket.org/user/gcloud.git;git -C /root/git/bt stash;git -C /root/git/bt pull https://user:pass@bitbucket.org/user/bt.git;python /root/git/v_a/d_s_e.py --r-day=1 --r-l=5;' > runner.sh "
```

Which worked until recently, but is now returning:

```
WARNING - POTENTIAL SECURITY BREACH!
The server's host key does not match the one PuTTY has
cached in the registry. This means that either the
server administrator has changed the host key, or you
have actually connected to another computer pretending
to be the server.
The new rsa2 key fingerprint is:
ssh-rsa blah
If you were expecting this change and trust the new key,
enter "y" to update PuTTY's cache and continue connecting.
If you want to carry on connecting but without updating
the cache, enter "n".
If you want to abandon the connection completely, press
Return to cancel. Pressing Return is the ONLY guaranteed
safe choice.
Update cached key? (y/n, Return cancels connection) stdin: is not a tty
```

As you can see in the command above, it is doing nothing but `echo`-ing into an `.sh` file.

If I delete the files in `C:\Users\%USER%\.ssh`, and rerun my gcloud ssh I get:

```
WARNING: The PuTTY PPK SSH key file for gcloud does not exist.
WARNING: The public SSH key file for gcloud does not exist.
WARNING: The private SSH key file for gcloud does not exist.
WARNING: You do not have an SSH key for gcloud.
WARNING: SSH keygen will be executed to generate a key.
Updating project ssh metadata...
.....................Updated [https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/my-project].
done.
Waiting for SSH key to propagate.
WARNING - POTENTIAL SECURITY BREACH!
The server's host key does not match the one PuTTY has
cached in the registry. This means that either the
server administrator has changed the host key, or you
have actually connected to another computer pretending
to be the server.
The new rsa2 key fingerprint is:
ssh-rsa foo
If you were expecting this change and trust the new key,
enter "y" to update PuTTY's cache and continue connecting.
If you want to carry on connecting but without updating
the cache, enter "n".
If you want to abandon the connection completely, press
Return to cancel. Pressing Return is the ONLY guaranteed
safe choice.
Update cached key? (y/n, Return cancels connection) stdin: is not a tty
```

Why am I getting this error message?  I only recently started receiving.

How do I avoid getting this error message? Is there a flag I may pass with my `gcloud ssh` command to programmatically update this cached key?

Thanks!

---

Edits to reply to Navi:

In my gcloud instance I have the following path:

```
/home/%USER%/.ssh
```

Locally, on my PC, I ran:

```
C:\>gcloud compute copy-files instance-v-a-20170826113548099000-l5-r1:/home/%USER%/.ssh C:/temp/ --zone us-east1-b
```

Additionally, locally I have the following path:

```
C:\Users\%USER%\.ssh
```

Which has the following `ls -l`:

```
$ ls -l
total 97
-rw-r--r-- 1 username 197121  1679 Apr  9 20:55 _google_compute_engine
-rw-r--r-- 1 username 197121  1454 Apr  9 20:56 _google_compute_engine.ppk
-rw-r--r-- 1 username 197121   422 Apr  9 20:55 _google_compute_engine.pub
-rw-r--r-- 1 username 197121 63368 Jul  7  2016 _known_hosts
-rw-r--r-- 1 username 197121   398 Jun 27  2016 _known_hosts.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 username 197121  1675 May 12  2015 github_rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 username 197121   408 May 12  2015 github_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r-- 1 username 197121  1679 Aug  5 17:41 google_compute_engine
-rw-r--r-- 1 username 197121  1454 Aug  5 17:41 google_compute_engine.ppk
-rw-r--r-- 1 username 197121  1454 Aug  5 13:21 google_compute_engine.ppk_
-rw-r--r-- 1 username 197121   422 Aug  5 17:41 google_compute_engine.pub
-rw-r--r-- 1 username 197121   422 Aug  5 13:21 google_compute_engine.pub_
-rw-r--r-- 1 username 197121  1679 Aug  5 13:21 google_compute_engine_
```

In experimenting to solve this issue I have renamed old files with underscores (this should not apply to the problem, only documenting).

Now, in metadata ssh keys I have the following:
[image]

In my `C:\temp\.ssh\authorized_keys` I have the following (truncated to not publicize my key):

```
# Added by Google
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC CookieMunster\jasonm@CookieMunster
```

And my local `C:\Users\%USER%\.ssh\google_compute_engine.ppk` has:

```
PuTTY-User-Key-File-2: ssh-rsa
Encryption: none
Comment: CookieMunster\jasonm@CookieMunster
Public-Lines: 6
AAAAB3NzaC
Private-Lines: 14
AAABA
Private-MAC: bd4
```

I have compared the full strings in notepad++ and they are identical, except the `google_compute_engine.ppk` file does not contain the computer name at the tail, but rather in the comment.

So Navi I do not think they differ.

---

My `systeminfo` command yields:

```
Host Name:                 PCNAME
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 8.1
OS Version:                6.3.9600 N/A Build 9600
OS Manufacturer:           Microsoft Corporation
OS Configuration:          Standalone Workstation
OS Build Type:             Multiprocessor Free
Registered Owner:          user
Registered Organization:   
Product ID:                00258-61265-96725-AAOEM
Original Install Date:     5/31/2014, 12:56:22 PM
System Boot Time:          9/1/2017, 12:32:41 AM
System Manufacturer:       Acer
System Model:              Aspire XC-603
System Type:               x64-based PC
Processor(s):              1 Processor(s) Installed.
                           [01]: Intel64 Family 6 Model 55 Stepping 3 GenuineIntel ~2408 Mhz
BIOS Version:              American Megatrends Inc. P11-A2, 1/23/2014
Windows Directory:         C:\Windows
System Directory:          C:\Windows\system32
Boot Device:               \Device\HarddiskVolume2
System Locale:             en-us;English (United States)
Input Locale:              N/A
Time Zone:                 (UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)
Total Physical Memory:     3,985 MB
Available Physical Memory: 734 MB
Virtual Memory: Max Size:  8,128 MB
Virtual Memory: Available: 2,523 MB
Virtual Memory: In Use:    5,605 MB
Page File Location(s):     C:\pagefile.sys
Domain:                    WORKGROUP
Logon Server:              \\PCNAME
Hotfix(s):                 117 Hotfix(s) Installed.
                           [01]: KB2899189_Microsoft-Windows-CameraCodec-Package
                           [02]: KB2868626
                           [03]: KB2883200
                           [04]: KB2884846
                           [05]: KB2887595
                           [06]: KB2894029
                           [07]: KB2894179
                           [08]: KB2894852
                           [09]: KB2894856
                           [10]: KB2896459
                           [11]: KB2900986
                           [12]: KB2903939
                           [13]: KB2910887
                           [14]: KB2911106
                           [15]: KB2913642
                           [16]: KB2919355
                           [17]: KB2919394
                           [18]: KB2919442
                           [19]: KB2920189
                           [20]: KB2921128
                           [21]: KB2928680
                           [22]: KB2954879
                           [23]: KB2955164
                           [24]: KB2958262
                           [25]: KB2959626
                           [26]: KB2959977
                           [27]: KB2961072
                           [28]: KB2961908
                           [29]: KB2962140
                           [30]: KB2962409
                           [31]: KB2965142
                           [32]: KB2965500
                           [33]: KB2966826
                           [34]: KB2966828
                           [35]: KB2967917
                           [36]: KB2968296
                           [37]: KB2969339
                           [38]: KB2971203
                           [39]: KB2972103
                           [40]: KB2972213
                           [41]: KB2973114
                           [42]: KB2975061
                           [43]: KB2975719
                           [44]: KB2976627
                           [45]: KB2977629
                           [46]: KB2977765
                           [47]: KB2978041
                           [48]: KB2978122
                           [49]: KB2978126
                           [50]: KB2979573
                           [51]: KB2979576
                           [52]: KB2984006
                           [53]: KB2987107
                           [54]: KB2989647
                           [55]: KB2989930
                           [56]: KB2990967
                           [57]: KB2993100
                           [58]: KB2994290
                           [59]: KB2995004
                           [60]: KB2995388
                           [61]: KB2996799
                           [62]: KB2998174
                           [63]: KB2999226
                           [64]: KB3000850
                           [65]: KB3003057
                           [66]: KB3003667
                           [67]: KB3004361
                           [68]: KB3004365
                           [69]: KB3004394
                           [70]: KB3006137
                           [71]: KB3008188
                           [72]: KB3008242
                           [73]: KB3008923
                           [74]: KB3011780
                           [75]: KB3012199
                           [76]: KB3012235
                           [77]: KB3012702
                           [78]: KB3013172
                           [79]: KB3013410
                           [80]: KB3014442
                           [81]: KB3016074
                           [82]: KB3018133
                           [83]: KB3019215
                           [84]: KB3019978
                           [85]: KB3020338
                           [86]: KB3021952
                           [87]: KB3022777
                           [88]: KB3022796
                           [89]: KB3023266
                           [90]: KB3023562
                           [91]: KB3024751
                           [92]: KB3024755
                           [93]: KB3025417
                           [94]: KB3027209
                           [95]: KB3029606
                           [96]: KB3029803
                           [97]: KB3030377
                           [98]: KB3030947
                           [99]: KB3032323
                           [100]: KB3032359
                           [101]: KB3033889
                           [102]: KB3034344
                           [103]: KB3034348
                           [104]: KB3035017
                           [105]: KB3035126
                           [106]: KB3035131
                           [107]: KB3035132
                           [108]: KB3035527
                           [109]: KB3035553
                           [110]: KB3035583
                           [111]: KB3036228
                           [112]: KB3036562
                           [113]: KB3036612
                           [114]: KB3039066
                           [115]: KB3044132
                           [116]: KB3046049
                           [117]: KB3102467
Network Card(s):           2 NIC(s) Installed.
                           [01]: Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
                                 Connection Name: Ethernet
                                 DHCP Enabled:    Yes
                                 DHCP Server:     000.000.1.1
                                 IP address(es)
                                 [01]: 000.000.0.155
                                 [02]: ffff::ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff
                           [02]: TAP-Windows Adapter V9
                                 Connection Name: Ethernet 2
                                 Status:          Media disconnected
Hyper-V Requirements:      VM Monitor Mode Extensions: Yes
                           Virtualization Enabled In Firmware: Yes
                           Second Level Address Translation: Yes
                           Data Execution Prevention Available: Yes
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to replicate this on MS server 2012 R2 using "Google Cloud SDK Shell" and did not receive the warning message. The most likely cause is that the RSA fingerprint has changed on the GCE server, but the client computer still has the previous RSA fingerprint stored.

Verify keys under C:\Users\%USER%.ssh directory files on the client machine matches with GCE instance user SSH keys present under /path-to-home-directory/.ssh directory files. Also, verify project-wide SSH keys under Cloud console > Compute Engine > Metadata > Check "SSH Keys" tab for available keys to match with the keys stored under client C:\Users\%USER%.ssh directory.

Do you receive same message even if you had selected "Y" to "Update cached key?" on client computer?

Edit: Attaching screen-shot. 
[image]

Comment: Sorry I just saw this. I will check and let you know shortly.

Comment: Navi - I am unable to hit "Y" since this is being done via ssh command sent to instance.

Comment: Navi - I have provided additional info regarding the points you made. Thank you in advance for additional guidance. I am **very** eager to get back up and running!

Comment: Also - just to comment, the only thing that appears not to work is the gcloud ssh. copy-files, instance creation and deletion etc all seem to work without issue.

Comment: Hi Navi - happy to throw some bounty onto this if helpful.

Comment: Hi Navi - whenever you have time. Thank you very much.

Comment: @jasonm Do you recieve the same message, if you try it from any other Windows machine with [gcloud SDK installed](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/downloads)?

Comment: I do not have access to another windows machine. This is my local server that is dedicated to my "prod" work. I doubt the error persists on a fresh box.

Comment: I already tried a clean install on gcloud sdk but continue to experience this issue. Is there a "hard reset" on these settings that we could do? I already deleted the registry variables that putty puts on the pc.

Comment: @jasonm Was there any changes made to the Windows machine before it stopped working? Which OS are you running on your client machine?

Comment: No only that time passed between usage. My remote is a Linux instance. I can provide more details on the instance later if helpful.

Comment: @jasonm Which OS is the client machine from where you are trying to connect to the remote Linux instance? and if any changes made to Windows machine before it stopped working? This possibly may be a client machine problem. If possible, try from different Windows client machine.

Comment: I do not have another windows machine

Comment: I will post machine details later today

Comment: i added the machine details above. There were no specific changes made to the PC that may have caused this issue.

Comment: Is there a way to cleanly remove any traces of RSA on the PC?

Comment: Navi this question is still pending.

Comment: @jasonm I would suggest to you verify with Windows system administrator as if problem seems to be related to a single client machine. I am not Windows expert, but it may be a permission issue on local client machine or the SSH keys stored under the registry on local client machine. I am still not able to replicate this on my end as When I press "Y" to "Update cached key?" on client computer while running the gcloud ssh command for the first time and second time I never receive the message.

Comment: It is a local pc. I am the administrator.

Comment: What did you run as your test command where you can hit yes or no to avoid the future error?

Comment: I am using "gcloud compute ssh my-instance --zone=us-central1-c" to connect to the system which updates the metadata SSH keys. I have attached screen-shot in my answer where in first attempt it ask to update the cache and in next attempt it just directly connected me to the instance without any message.

Comment: I will try later today and let you know

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the public key from the server you are trying to connect to has changed and doesn't match the one you had stored, so this is why gcloud is freaking out.

The easiest way to solve the issue is doing this once:

```
gcloud compute ssh [YOUR INSTANCE NAME] --force-key-file-overwrite
```

From the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh):

```
--force-key-file-overwrite

If enabled, the gcloud command-line tool will regenerate and overwrite the files associated with a broken SSH key without asking for confirmation in both interactive and non-interactive environments.
If disabled, the files associated with a broken SSH key will not be regenerated and will fail in both interactive and non-interactive environments.
```

This should overwrite the pubkey you have stored for this server. After this when you connect you won't be getting any errors, at least until the ssh key for the server changes again.